# OpenCV For remove watermark

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying `cv2.inpaint`, if you add watermark by myself, and then use `cv2.inpaint`, the result is perfect.

But, if I use internet image like below:

Source Image

[image]

Watermark image
[image]

The result is bad.

Here is the code

```
zhihuimage = cv2.imread('../input/zhihumask/OpenCV_11.jpg')
zhihuwatermask = cv2.imread('../input/zhihumask/OpenCV_22.jpg')
# remove watermark with mark
zhihuwatermask = cv2.cvtColor(zhihuwatermask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
zhihuoutput = cv2.inpaint(zhihuimage, zhihuwatermask,3, flags= cv2.INPAINT_NS)
```

Comment: the result is bad? please show the result too

Comment: The result is the same as original image. You could run with code and images.@Christoph Rackwitz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the watermark mask and the watermark in the image are not aligned, you can dilate the mask to compensate for small mis-alignments.

Code with dilate that removes the watermark properly:

```
zhihuimage = cv2.imread('../input/zhihumask/OpenCV_11.jpg')
zhihuwatermask = cv2.imread('../input/zhihumask/OpenCV_22.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
# remove watermark with mark
dilatekernel = np.ones((5, 5), 'uint8')
zhihuwatermask = cv2.dilate(zhihuwatermask, dilatekernel)
zhihuoutput = cv2.inpaint(zhihuimage, zhihuwatermask, 3, flags=cv2.INPAINT_NS)
```

Comment: Yeah, it really works, but could you share how to get the value for `dilatekernel`? I am wondering how to get the `(5, 5)`

Comment: It's depends on how mis-align is the watermark, usually you can use a little larger then required kernel without  any major visual "damage", if you are not satisfied with the result, I suggest using cv2.matchTemplate to find the exact location of each word in the watermark and then using cv2.inpaint

Comment: could you share more detail about `cv2.matchTemplate`?